# Oscillation motion

Tags: oscillators

My question is: despite there being a direct proportionality relationship between displacement and acceleration in SHM, why is it that, if displacement is greater than zero, then acceleration would be less than zero and vice-versa.

Comment: there is a negative sign in the proportionality relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a direct proportionality relationship between displacement and acceleration(acceleration = constant * displacement) but with the negative constant

acceleration = - (frequency)^2 * displacement

Answer (score 1):

Simple harmonic motion occurs when there is a restoring force. That is, an object has a position where the force is $0$. When the object moves away from that position, there is a force pushing it back. The strength of the force is proportional to the distance away.

$$F = -k(x-x_0)$$

Let us suppose that $x_0 = 0$, and $x > 0$. Then $x$ is to the right of $0$, and the force pushes to the left. $F$ is in the negative direction. This is the origin of the negative sign in the equation.